# PRESTO + dose presto cordinator can manage 160 workers node?

Tags: linux, database, performance-testing, presto, trino

We have a presto cluster with 160 worker nodes.

- presto coordinator installed on VM machine ( 32G + 16 CPU )
  and all other are worker machines ( physical machines )

**the basic question is - - if the machine with the presto coordinator can serve 160 workers machines**

additional to that:

1. How we  do the sizing  for presto coordinator (memory,cpu)?
2. What is the best practice sizing formula for the coordinator machine?
3. Dose presto coordinator can handle and manage 160 workers machines ? ,
4. Dose Presto coordinator machine is limited to manage until X workers machines ?

[image]

reverence - http://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/overview/concepts.html

**Coordinator**
The Presto coordinator is the server that is responsible for parsing statements, planning queries, and managing Presto worker nodes. It is the “brain” of a Presto installation and is also the node to which a client connects to submit statements for execution. Every Presto installation must have a Presto coordinator alongside one or more Presto workers. For development or testing purposes, a single instance of Presto can be configured to perform both roles.

The coordinator keeps track of the activity on each worker and coordinates the execution of a query. The coordinator creates a logical model of a query involving a series of stages which is then translated into a series of connected tasks running on a cluster of Presto workers.

Coordinators communicate with workers and clients using a REST API.

**Worker**
A Presto worker is a server in a Presto installation which is responsible for executing tasks and processing data. Worker nodes fetch data from connectors and exchange intermediate data with each other. The coordinator is responsible for fetching results from the workers and returning the final results to the client.

When a Presto worker process starts up, it advertises itself to the discovery server in the coordinator, which makes it available to the Presto coordinator for task execution.

Workers communicate with other workers and Presto coordinators using a REST API.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is, and what you are asking. Please clearly state the problem and ask a question.

Comment: what I am asking is - if the machine with the presto coordinator can serve 160 workers machines

Comment: done - I update the question and thank you

Comment: I will happy if you can help me with the question -:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** in general, coordinator can easily handle much more worker nodes than 160, but your milage may vary.

**Longer version**
Presto coordinator can manage 1000 workers.
However, you're asking for a coordinator with particular memory and CPU resources. The answer is -- *it depends*.

The coordinator tracks tasks execution across workers, and so memory limits depend on the complexity of your queries. Also, when you're querying partitioned tables (e.g. in S3, Hive), some information about the partitions accessed by the query needs, by necessity, be kept in the memory. When you have multiple queries, this adds up.

Comment: thank you so much , I have another note - on my VM machine with the presto coordinator also have other 8-9 services that are running on that machine as zookeper server , name node , yarn service etc , so do you recommended to dedicated a new machine for the presto coordinator ? and what is the minimal requirements for the presto coordinator ?  ( CPU , memory , etc )

Comment: by the way we installed the latest presto version , and we are using ambari cluster , while the presto coordinator installed on master01 machines and all presto servers are installed on the datanode machines ( 160 workers machines )

Comment: Presto process queries in-memory, so you want to assign a reasonable heap size to each Presto process (including the coordinator, which needs memory to control workers' work). It's easier to tune Presto when it is installed on separate machines, but I understand you are constrained by the hardware you have. So you need to split physical memory across processes and ensure you don't over-allocate. Mind that Java uses more memory more than just the heap (i.e. more than -Xmx), so this isn't a trivial exercise.